# ng-repeat showing wrong values in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<ion-item
  class="item-icon-left item-icon-right item-avatar"
  ng-repeat="note in taskDetails.notes track by note.note_id"
  ng-click="viewNote(note)">
  <i ng-show="note.status.name==Open" class="icon ion-ios-circle-outline"></i>
  <i ng-show="note.status.name!=Open"class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i>
  <h2>{{note.note}}</h2>
  <p>{{note.created_by}}</p>
  <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
</ion-item>
```

> Task Object
>
> {"task_date_id":69069,"task_id":"3286","start_time":"2018-02-22 12:10:00","end_time":"2018-02-22 12:10:00","overdue_days":0,"subject":"Oneone","description":"One","status":{"id":3,"name":"Pending","enabled":null,"complete":null},"statuses":[{"id":3,"name":"Pending"},{"id":6,"name":"Assigned"},{"id":4,"name":"Closed"},{"id":17,"name":"Complete"}],"type":{"id":229,"name":"200_Test_Mobile_Task"},"assigned_to":"Kanishka Raveendra","address":"","clients":[],"attachments":[],"notes":[],"$$hashKey":"object:8112"}
>
> Note Object
>
> {"note_id":"98834","note_date":"22/02/2018","note_type":"ABC14","time_spent":0,"note":"Xyxhxffuf\n
>
> {$PERSON_FIRST_NAME}
>   {$PERSON_SURNAME}
>
> ","created_by":"Kanishka
>   Raveendra","date_created":"","attachments":[],"template":"
>
> {$PERSON_FIRST_NAME}
>   {$PERSON_SURNAME}
>
> ","type":{"id":52,"name":"ABC14","enabled":true,"record_time":"start_stop"}}

here I added source code and response of Task and Note which I used to show the data.Normally one task can have a number of notes.But Here clearly we can see notes array has no elements.But I can see some notes objects from others tasks in the View.I need to show correct values of notes in View.please help me.I'm new to ionic.

> Console error
>
> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: note in taskDetails.notes track by note.note_id, Duplicate key: 98834, Duplicate value: {"note_id":"98834","note_date":"22/02/2018","note_type":"ABC14","time_spent":0,"note":"Xyxhxffuf\n
>
> {$PERSON_FIRST_NAME} {$PERSON_SURNAME}
>
> ","created_by":"Kanishka Raveendra","date_created":"","attachments":[],"template":"
>
> {$PERSON_FIRST_NAME} {$PERSON_SURNAME}
>
> ","type":{"id":52,"name":"ABC14","enabled":true,"record_time":"start_stop"}}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Without note values View showing some notes.Notes array is empty in the task object

Comment: It would be empty if there are no notes. Please explain what behavior you expect. Define "correct" and explain how the current behavior is not "correct".

Comment: in "note in taskDetails.notes track by note.note_id", taskDetails is there but in JSON where is taskDetail field..?

Comment: I assigned task details to scope. taskDetail .So I access task object values using  taskDetail

Comment: @AluanHaddad - In the view I have task list.So when I click on task it will show the details of that particular task.So inside that task there is a note array.My problem is notes are not correctly shown .

Comment: Hi all, I added console log error.Have look at it.

Comment: clear your cahce

Comment: Thank you all.I solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `track by note.note_id` getting the same value.

Use `$index` which is iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1) in `ng-repeat`.

Please check for more details from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Use the following solution :

```
      <ion-item
        class="item-icon-left item-icon-right item-avatar"
        ng-repeat="note in taskDetails.notes track by $index"
        ng-click="viewNote(note)">
        <i class="icon" ng-class="{'ion-ios-circle-outline': note.status.name === 'Open', 'ion-ios-checkmark-outline': note.status.name !== 'Open'}"></i>

        <h2>{{note.note}}</h2>
        <p>{{note.created_by}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
```

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Hi Santhosh,What is $index?

Comment: iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

Comment: is it ok if I add "note in taskDetails.notes track by $index" to my code

Comment: yes , please check it then you don't have error on your console

Comment: Okay also use ng-class in place of multiple ng-show to apply dynamic class

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ion-item
        class="item-icon-left item-icon-right item-avatar"
        ng-repeat="(key, value) in taskDetails.notes track by $index"
        ng-click="viewNote(note)">
        ......
</ion-item>
```